# range() as method argument for loop iterator

Tags: iterator, range, cython

this code generates a nice loop :

for i in range(self.ix):

```
__pyx_t_3 = __pyx_v_self->ix;
__pyx_t_4 = __pyx_t_3;
for (__pyx_t_5 = 0; __pyx_t_5 < __pyx_t_4; __pyx_t_5+=1) {
  __pyx_v_i = __pyx_t_5;
```

but i want to be able to pass this iterator as argument (so i can have different iterators/generators)

if i try this :

```
  cdef ixrange(self): return range(self.ix)
```

already is too unwieldy and the loop is no longer a simple loop. :

```
static PyObject *__pyx_f_3lib_10sparse_ary_9SparseAry_ixrange(struct __pyx_obj_3lib_10sparse_ary_SparseAry *__pyx_v_self) {
  PyObject *__pyx_r = NULL;
  __Pyx_RefNannyDeclarations
  __Pyx_RefNannySetupContext("ixrange", 0);
  __Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_r);
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_unsigned_int(__pyx_v_self->ix); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 139, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyObject_CallOneArg(__pyx_builtin_range, __pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 139, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_r = __pyx_t_2;
  __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  goto __pyx_L0;

  /* function exit code */
  __pyx_L1_error:;
  __Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_AddTraceback("lib.sparse_ary.SparseAry.ixrange", __pyx_clineno, __pyx_lineno, __pyx_filename);
  __pyx_r = 0;
  __pyx_L0:;
  __Pyx_XGIVEREF(__pyx_r);
  __Pyx_RefNannyFinishContext();
  return __pyx_r;
}
```

any way i can make it simple loop again ?

Comment: But it isn't a for loop; it's a function that returns a `range` object. It looks like Cython is doing the right thing here

Comment: i understand it is doing the right thing.. my q is if there is way to inline the range-case, so it generate simple loop... and then still have to be able to pass other generators/iteraors

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible.

The effect of `for i in range(self.ix):` is to generate a `range` object, and then call `next` on that range object until a `StopIteration` exception is raised. That's also the behaviour that Cython takes for general for loops.

There's actually a fairly long list of conditions that have to be met for Cython to transform that into an optimized loop:

- range must be used directly - i.e. `it = range(...); for i in it` won't work because you might need the `range` object after the loop.
- the types of the start and stop point must be integers.
- the type of the loop variable must be an integer (Cython can infer this, but if you assign something of a different type to the loop variable then it won't work)
- Cython must know that you haven't reassigned `range`
- The sign of the stop variable must be known.

In your case I think you're hoping for Cython to look inside the `cdef` function and pick out the range. This is beyond what the current optimizer can do. But also, you can override `cdef` functions in a derived class (in C++ terms, they're "virtual"), so Cython could almost never safely make the optimization.

Cython is usually able to optimize best when you really restrict the types it's working with. The request that it should generate a fast C for loop but also be able to handle arbitrary iterators does not seem realistically achievable.

Comment: so the only way is to add if cond : range-loop else : it-loop

Comment: That's the old thing I can think of.